# Two statements explanation

Tags: android

Are this

```
Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
```

and this having the same meaning?

```
findViewById(R.id.btnMap).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
```

And what is the the difference  and the role of each one?

Comment: No, they are **not**. By the way, the second one looks very weird to me and should be rewritten as `btnMap.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
```

This is the definition and typecasting of your button. Here you named a button 'btnMap' which has id of 'btnMap'(in your xml file).

```
(yourButton).setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
```

This sets an onClick listner to the specific button.

Diffrence is one is just definition of an element and second is a statement which would give an element a behaviour (i.e. Click).

This is the most simple language I can use to describe these.